# "invalid argument: 'name' must be a string" when trying to set Edge driver on Watir

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to add edge driver to our automation tests suite.
I am setting the driver like that:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Edge::Service.driver_path = EDGEDRIVER_PATH
    Watir::Browser.new BROWSER.to_sym,{:unexpected_alert_behaviour => 'ignore',  "edgeOptions" => {'w3c' => false, :args => args} }
```

When I am trying to maximize window size with
`@browser.window.maximize`
I am getting this error:

```
invalid argument: 'name' must be a string
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=85.0.564.44)
  (Driver info: msedgedriver=85.0.564.44 (3b106b45f8e7cd4c3e2aac5a6ba411645c16df60),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This could be an issue ! Try with firefox and chrome, If it works better you open the issue in GitHub.

Comment: @Rajagopalan The problem is only with edge driver

Comment: Then raise the ticket in GitHub.